# Why does reqwest download a binary file as text?

Tags: web-scraping, rust, mp3

I am trying to scrape a page that automatically downloads an mp3 file `https://dl251.filemate24.shop/?file=M3R4SUNiN3JsOHJ6WWRQNXNPUFN2cFdxRVJIOGhmSXBsY1l1d2hrdFN1QnRxNGc5M3UraGFPWkpLSzRNeEl1dVd1aGQ4VHZYVG9uZE93MlpwZFlyVWlESDhkOHh2QURmOHBvb0JJd2pjQS8zanZLMmxEUXoyeUg0Ym91SVI1NE9LQ1Zka1ZJNzN5eWh5L0wrbHpqSDZpdW1wVjJRSWlrYTRYME1PUHFOeEt3TzBISGJadVhoeDVrSXFIdk90Y29maTZYTDVWYWdoYUE3dnVOMlZrRjNlTTBNbjRuamd2VE8vQT09` but using a get request and putting the output in a .txt file results in a 28,000 line long  file of random unicode characters. Is there any way to get the actual mp3 file? And yes, I am trying to download a random rammstein song as a test for a larger project.

I checked using inspect element and all the site does is indeed one get request that somehow results in a file. I'm pretty sure that the random unicode is related to LAME mp3 encryption, but I'm not sure how. Is there any way to get an mp3 file from a get request? Rust code that results in said file:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn get(url: &str,client: &reqwest::Client) -> String {
    let response = client
    .get(url).send()
    .await
    .unwrap()
    .text()
    .await
    .expect("GET failed");

    response

}
fn main() {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let url = "https://dl251.filemate24.shop/?file=M3R4SUNiN3JsOHJ6WWRQNXNPUFN2cFdxRVJIOGhmSXBsY1l1d2hrdFN1QnRxNGc5M3UraGFPWkpLSzRNeEl1dVd1aGQ4VHZYVG9uZE93MlpwZFlyVWlESDhkOHh2QURmOHBvb0JJd2pjQS8zanZLMmxEUXoyeUg0Ym91SVI1NE9LQ1Zka1ZJNzN5eWh5L0wrbHpqSDZpdW1wVjJRSWlrYTRYME1PUHFOeEt3TzBISGJadVhoeDVrSXFIdk90Y29maTZYTDVWYWdoYUE3dnVOMlZrRjNlTTBNbjRuamd2VE8vQT09";
    println!("{}",url);
    let mp3 = get(url,&client);
    let mut file = std::fs::File::create("a.txt");
    std::fs::write("a.txt",mp3);
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question; I'm pretty new to rust and coding in general.

Comment: Point of clarification: LAME does not perform "MP3 encryption." Encryption is a technique to render data unreadable without some kind of secret. LAME does audio _transcoding_ which is simply audio from one representation (e.g. WAV) into another representation (e.g. MP3). No secret is required to decode MP3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing text data because you're *asking for text data* when you use `.text()` on the response.  According to the [`.text()` documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text):

> This method decodes the response body with BOM sniffing and with malformed sequences replaced with the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

In other words, this *modifies* the response to be valid text by replacing any bytes that don't represent valid text with a special Unicode character.  This ensures the result is valid as a Rust `String` (which, by definition, must be UTF-8 encoded text).  **Effectively, this function call corrupts the MP3 data you're expecting to download.**

Use `.bytes()` instead, and change the return type of `get()` to `Vec<u8>`.

As a side note, you're using async (tokio) when it's not necessary. Consider instead using [`reqwest::blocking`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/index.html).